# Is it possible to convert my React DOM (animation) into a video or gif?

Tags: reactjs, animation, dom-events

I'm trying to convert my animations i have created into a gif or video.
The date of the animations (text and picture) comes from the api. There should be a function that allows the user to download the animation as a video. Something like Instagram stories. Is it possible to implement?

I tried to solve this issue using Chat openai. I got the answer like this. I tried to make the same but unsuccessfully [chat.openai.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUHJU.png)

Comment: Not a straight forward task, look into https://www.remotion.dev/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.